# Use commands with parentheses like diff in shell script

Tags: shell, diff

I want to diff output from 2 commands

diff output from
**cat file1** and **cat file2**

And I found that the solution is

```
diff <(cat file1) <(cat file2)
```

However

If I **put this in a shell script**
The parentheses cannot be recognized since it means calling sub-shell in shell script.. (I wonder if what I know is correct)

```
#!bin/bash
diff <(cat $1) <(cat $2)
```

syntax error near unexpected token `('

Is there any solution to use commands requiring parentheses in shell script ?

I've tried

```
 diff `<(cat $1) <(cat $2)`
 diff `<(cat $1)` `<(cat $2)`
 diff "<(cat $1) <(cat $2)"
 diff <`(`cat $1`)` <`(`cat $2`)`
```

but none of the above works

I used to dump output to other files and compare those files

```
cat $1 > out1.txt
cat $2 > out2.txt
diff -b out1.txt out2.txt
```

I know this could work, but I just want to know if there's any way without dumping the output to files beforehand

Comment: I suspect you are trying to run the script with `sh yourScript.sh`, which ignores the shebang. `sh` (even if it's a link to `bash`) doesn't support process substitution.

Comment: Yes I run my script with sh, so I can run it with other command and this would work?

Comment: Your shebang is wrong. `#!bin/bash` != `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a script containing `bash` commands, you need to run it with `bash`, not `sh`. (Consider: Would you expect `rm scriptfile` to run the bash commands contained in the file?)

If you want something more portable, you can use FIFOs explicitly (in particular, the `mkfifo` command):

```
#!/bin/sh

mkfifo fifo1 fifo2
cat "$1" >>fifo1 &
cat "$2" >>fifo2 &
diff -b fifo1 fifo2
rm fifo1 fifo2
```

Comment: I tried bash and it worked!  I also want to know ifyour example provided here is same as dumping them files and delete them after the diff command?

Comment: My example is approximately what bash is doing except bash ensures the FIFO names don't clash with anything else. A FIFO is also known as a "named pipe" (as in the `|` pipe operator). Only a buffer worth of data is stored, not the entire file contents.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for all the useful information, learned a lot from what your responded!

Answer (score 0):

i tried this test.sh and get the right  output.

```
#! /bin/bash
diff <(cat $1) <(cat $2)
```

Comment: this doens't work, but I think it's because I used 'sh', not 'bash'